# Is there a javascript/jquery event to where to detect text in an input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would want the function to detect whether there is text in a text field typed in by a user. Not necessarily keyup. I wouldn't want it to fire every time I type in the field. I would want it to detect whether there is text in the field or not.

Comment: Do you mean the [`input` event?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html `<input>` tags including type='text' support the [onchange event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).  The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been changed.

> I wouldn't want it to fire every time I type in the field.

in this case, when exactly would you want it to be triggered? [onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) event occurs when an object loses focus.

Comment: for me it's the proper way wait that the element have really change and after check the lenght or the value to determine if it's empty or filled

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 another events like 'blur' or 'focus'